# Pandas replace change so values to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan

I have the the following dataframe:

```
# dictionary with list object in values
details = {
    'Name' : ['D', 'C', 'F', 'G','A','N'],
    'values' : ['21%','45%','10%',12,14,15],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

The column value has values in %, however, some were originally saves as string with symbol % and some as number.  I would like to get rid of the % and have them all as int type. For that I have used replace and then as_type. however, when I repalce the '%', the values that son't have % change to Nan values:

```
df['values']=df['values'].str.replace('%', '')

df

>>> Name    values
0   D        21
1   C        45
2   F        10
3   G       NaN
4   A       NaN
5   N       NaN
```

My **reuired output** should be:

```
>>> Name    values
0   D        21
1   C        45
2   F        10
3   G        12
4   A        14
5   N        15
```

My question is, how can I get rid of the % and get the column with the values , without getting these NaN values? and why is this happenning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numeric values, so if use `str` function get missing values for numeric, possible solution is use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `regex=True` for replace by substring and then because get numeric with strings convert output to integers:

```
df['values']=df['values'].replace('%', '', regex=True).astype(int)
print (df)
  Name  values
0    D      21
1    C      45
2    F      10
3    G      12
4    A      14
5    N      15
```

Or your solution with replace missing values:

```
df['values']=df['values'].str.replace('%', '').fillna(df['values']).astype(int)
```

Comment: thank you! how do you always answer so quickly ?